# React. Filter the result upon click the checkbox input

Tags: reactjs

This is my first time here. So i plan to filter the result (remove item that stocked=false / item with red name) upon click the checkbox input.

i have try filter it in the const filter by checking the toggle is true and false but failed.

Additionally i hope to shorten my code while make it easier to read and understand as i am still new to this. Thanks in advance. i got the project from react-beta btw but i dont want to follow the code cause i dont understand it. This is the
link: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/thinking-in-react

```
import {useState} from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
const items = [
  { category: "Fruits", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Apple" },
  { category: "Fruits", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Dragonfruit" },
  { category: "Fruits", price: "$2", stocked: false, name: "Passionfruit" },
  { category: "Vegetables", price: "$2", stocked: true, name: "Spinach" },
  { category: "Vegetables", price: "$4", stocked: false, name: "Pumpkin" },
  { category: "Vegetables", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Peas" },
];
export default function Sort1() {
  const [fruits, setFruits] = useState("");
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const filter = items.filter((e) =>
    e.name.toLowerCase().includes(fruits.toLowerCase())
  );
  function togglefilter(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setToggle(true);
    } else {
      setToggle(false);
    }
    console.log("toggle is " + e.target.checked);
  }
  // filter2 to select only category fruits
  const filter2 = filter.filter((e) => (e.category === "Fruits" ? e : ""));
  // filter3 to select only category vege
  const filter3 = filter.filter((e) => (e.category === "Vegetables" ? e : ""));
  function Filtered() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>Name</Col>
          <Col>Price</Col>
        </Row>
        {/* fruits filter */}
        {filter2.length == 0 ? (
          ""
        ) : (
          <>
            <Row>
              <Col>Fruits</Col>
            </Row>
            {filter2.map((e, index) => {
              return (
                <Row key={index}>
                  {" "}
                  <Col>
                    {e.stocked ? (
                      e.name
                    ) : (
                      <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{e.name}</span>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                  <Col>{e.price}</Col>
                </Row>
              );
            })}
          </>
        )}
        {/* vegetables filter */}
        {filter3.length == 0 ? (
          ""
        ) : (
          <>
            <Row>
              <Col>Vegetables</Col>
            </Row>
            {filter3.map((e, index) => {
              return (
                <Row key={index}>
                  {" "}
                  <Col>
                    {e.stocked ? (
                      e.name
                    ) : (
                      <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{e.name}</span>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                  <Col>{e.price}</Col>
                </Row>
              );
            })}
          </>
        )}
      </Container>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: "50px",
        border: "solid 1px black",
        width: "600px",
        minHeight: "300px",
      }}
    >
      <input
        value={fruits}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFruits(e.target.value);
        }}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        style={{ margin: "20px", marginBottom: "0" }}
      />
      <br />
      <h6 style={{ color: "red", fontSize: "10px" }}>
        *red indicate unavailable items
      </h6>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={toggle} onChange={togglefilter} /> Only
        Show Products in stock
      </label>
      <p>Search: {fruits}</p>
      <Filtered />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your items conditionally. Whenever `toggle` state is `true` filter them based on `stocked` property.

```
// Execute the following line conditionally based on `toggle` state
const inStockItems = items.filter((item) => item.stocked)
```

Comment: Hi what line do i use the code in? i tried to replace function in toggle but it didnt work as react error come out inStockItems is not a function.

Comment: It depends on your implementation.`inStockItems` is just an arbitrary name. The point is how to filter the `items` to get the items that are in stock. You can use `map` over the filtered array and create elements based on the filtered data. You can render `inStockItems` or `filter4` the way you rendered other filtered items.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `filterObject` and to apply filtering with useMemo. Also, consider using useMemo and useState hooks, they will prevent your components from unneded rerendering and reevaluations.

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { items as all_items } from "./data";

export default function Sort1() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(all_items);

  const [filterObject, setFilterObject] = useState({
    name: "",
    isStockedOnly: false
  });

  const filteredItems = useMemo(() => {
    if (!items || !filterObject) return [];
    let filtered = [...items];
    const { name, isStockedOnly } = filterObject;
    if (name && name.length > 0) {
      filtered = filtered.filter((x) =>
        x.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
    if (isStockedOnly) {
      filtered = filtered.filter((x) => x.stocked === isStockedOnly);
    }
    return filtered;
  }, [items, filterObject]);

  const filteredFruits = useMemo(() => {
    return filteredItems.filter((x) => x.category === "Fruits");
  }, [filteredItems]);

  const filteredVegetables = useMemo(() => {
    return filteredItems.filter((x) => x.category === "Vegetables");
  }, [filteredItems]);

  function togglefilter(e) {
    setFilterObject((prev) => ({ ...prev, isStockedOnly: e.target.checked }));
  }

  function Filtered() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>Name</Col>
          <Col>Price</Col>
        </Row>
        {/* fruits filter */}
        {filteredFruits?.length > 0 && (
          <>
            <Row>
              <Col>Fruits</Col>
            </Row>
            {filteredFruits.map((e, index) => {
              return (
                <Row key={index}>
                  {" "}
                  <Col>
                    {e.stocked ? (
                      e.name
                    ) : (
                      <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{e.name}</span>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                  <Col>{e.price}</Col>
                </Row>
              );
            })}
          </>
        )}
        {/* vegetables filter */}
        {filteredVegetables?.length > 0 && (
          <>
            <Row>
              <Col>Vegetables</Col>
            </Row>
            {filteredVegetables.map((e, index) => {
              return (
                <Row key={index}>
                  {" "}
                  <Col>
                    {e.stocked ? (
                      e.name
                    ) : (
                      <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{e.name}</span>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                  <Col>{e.price}</Col>
                </Row>
              );
            })}
          </>
        )}
      </Container>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: "50px",
        border: "solid 1px black",
        width: "600px",
        minHeight: "300px"
      }}
    >
      <input
        value={filterObject.name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFilterObject((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: e.target.value }));
        }}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        style={{ margin: "20px", marginBottom: "0" }}
      />
      <br />
      <h6 style={{ color: "red", fontSize: "10px" }}>
        *red indicate unavailable items
      </h6>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={filterObject.isStockedOnly}
          onChange={togglefilter}
        />{" "}
        Only Show Products in stock
      </label>
      <p>Search: {filterObject.name}</p>
      <Filtered />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit peaceful-zeh-1l8cee]

UPD: Clarifications

Basically the idea is to have 1 `items` array as a state variable that holds the data loaded.

Next - state variable `filterObject`, just to keep everything search-related in 1 object.

Next - the `filteredItems` that are returned by useMemo hook which runs the function passed to it when anything in the `depsArray`, `[items, filterObject]` in our case is changed. It just watch for changes of `items` and `filterObject` and filters items based on what is in `filterObject` and returns array that match all the criterias.

Next - 2 useMemo hooks for fruits and vegetables, they just take the filtered array and apply 1 more filter by `category`, now you have 1 full array `items` with everything, 1 `filteredItems`, and 2 separate collections of fruits and vegetables, which are extracted from `filteredItems`.

Now just render them, and bind your `inputs` to change `filterObject` state.

Comment: Thanks. The code works but i hardly understand many parts of it. i think i will take sometime to understand and digest the information.